# Saving server credentials on repo on GitHub : Recommendations

Tags: php, git, github, passwords, config

Consider from the view point of wev developer, a public running site, whose code is to be made public but some data transactions on the site occur via php to MySQL server.

Code like this is usually,

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

placed in a file `connect.php` which is used to initiate connections.

1. What would be the best way to prevent public access to this file's content over GitHub public repo.
2. If in case `.gitignore` is used to remove the file from the repo, can we still keep the repo in sync with the webserver's serving directory.

**Would like to know what would be the recommended way.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are approaching this problem from the wrong side. The solution is to never put confidential information into Git or any other VCS.

**Don't hardcode the username and password.** The whole reason why you have it in a variable is because these details should be variable and come from outside the file.

There are two generally recommended practices:

1. Store username and password in environment variables. Using environment variables in PHP is quite easy and it ensures these values are outside your VCS.
2. Store username and password in a config file outside of your web root directory. The config file can either be a PHP file or INI file. The important thing is not to include it in VCS and don't put it in a place accessible from the internet. You can then include the file or use [`parse_ini_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) to get the configuration settings. If you can you might also include it in the virtual host config file.

On another note:

Your code is vulnerable to credential leaking anyways. Never check for MySQLi connection errors manually. Please read [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)

The correct way of connecting using MySQLi is this:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $env_dbusername, $env_dbpassword, 'db_test');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset
```

If you can, avoid MySQLi and use PDO instead.

Comment: Could you add documentation links for both options mentioned. I did not know of above techniques. (I hardcoded !!)

Comment: mysqli documentation is horrifyingly bad. I would not recommend relying on it. There is a little bit written here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php and here https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php